# Consulta SELECT MYSQL tablas no relacionadas

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada compras
[image: compras]

Y una llamada ventas
[image: ventas]

de las cuales necesito obtener una suma total agrupada por mes.
SOlo para dar un ejemplo de lo que intento hacer tengo esta consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(creado) as meses,
IFNULL(SUM(total),0) as total_mes  FROM ventas WHERE YEAR(creado) =
'2018' AND idsucursal='1' AND estado='Enviado' GROUP BY meses ORDER BY
meses DESC) as ventas,(SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(fecha_compra) as mesess,
IFNULL(SUM(total),0) as total_mes_compras  FROM compras WHERE
YEAR(fecha_compra) = '2018' AND idsucursal='1' AND estado='Aceptado'
```

GROUP BY mesess ORDER BY mesess DESC)as compras GROUP BY meses,mesess

y el resultado que obtengo es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el resultado que quiero obtener seria asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

favor si me pueden ayudar, que ya estoy que me rompo la cabeza.gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizar los dos subqueries por separado y luego los unes, de esa forma obtendrás lo que esperas.

A continuación te presento un ejemplo, el cual lo probe con tablas de un esquema que tengo en mi computadora, pero los cambie a las tablas y campos de tu ejemplo, por lo que algo puede fallar, pero esto te servirá de guía para obtener el resultado esperado.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT s.mes, sum(s.total_mes_venta), sum(s.total_mes_compra) FROM 
(
    SELECT MONTH(creado) mes, sum(total) AS total_mes_venta, 0 AS total_mes_compra FROM ventas
    WHERE YEAR(creado) = '2018' AND idsucursal='1' AND estado='Enviado'
    GROUP BY MONTH(creado)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH(fecha_compra) mes, 0 as total_mes_venta, SUM(total) AS total_mes_compra FROM compras
    WHERE YEAR(fecha_compra) = '2018' AND idsucursal='1' AND estado='Aceptado'
    GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_compra)
) s
GROUP BY s.mes
```

Comment: estimado, que quiere que le diga! muchas gracias. su repuesta es lo que buscaba.!!

Comment: Excelente! Fue un placer poder ayudarle

Comment: yo tambien tengo una conbsulta, qiero eliminar todos los registros de una tabla donde el campos fecha no coincida de otra tabla, es decir que solo se guarde  las fechas iguales en ambas tablas, las tablas no las tengo relacionadas, y me sale un error.  DELETE FROM promedio_total WHERE fecha<>fecha_registro;   el campos fecha pertenece a la tabla promedio_total y el campo fecha_registro pertenece a otra tabla.